# How to unregister a widget from a child theme

Tags: plugins, widgets

I was wondering if there was a way to unregister a widget that gets declared in the functions.php file of a parent theme from a child theme, I understand that the child's function.php file gets loaded first so I don't know how to unregister it when it hasn't been created yet.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the Parent Theme's Widget is registered at the `widgets_init` hook, all you need to do is wrap your `unregister_widget()` call inside of a function, hook that function into `widgets_init`, and give your hook a higher **priority number** than the Parent Theme's `widgets_init`-hooked function.

Assuming the Parent Theme hooks into `widgets_init` without giving a priority number, the function will default to `10`. So, just give your hook call a priority of `11` or greater.

Answer (score 1):

A priority of 11 might not work so try this in your child themes functions file:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'unregister_a_widget', 99 );

function unregister_a_widget() {

    unregister_widget( 'Your_Widget_Class' );

}
```

Swap out Your_Widget_Class with the class for your widget.